# How to make the terminal prompt make sound every time i am prompted to write a command?

Tags: command-line, scripts, prompt

I want every time i have the command prompt (i.e, end of a command) to get a sound to get attention to the terminal `[as i am using laptop \a character is not going to work with me]`.
The command i want to run is: `mplayer /home/naruto/Music/sfx_msg-highlight.wv &> /dev/null &` i put it in a sound.sh file and i make it accessible but when i add ./sound.sh to my .bashrc --> ps1 it just prints it [you can also see my ps1 in the background].
[image]

so how to make this work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer,
just `\[$(COMMAND)` to run a command with every terminal prompt.
For me i just put the command in a script and then run it by putting `\[$(~/sound2.sh \# \u)` at the end of the ps1 variable and before the ending ` of it --> in the .bashrc file
And the script is:

```
if [ $1 = 1 ]; then
    spd-say "Welcome $2" &
else
    mplayer /home/naruto/Music/sfx_msg-highlight.wv &> /dev/null &
fi
```

The script takes 2 arguments:

- `$1` is the Number of commands entered into this shell session.
  to know if you just opened the terminal then the terminal will say hello followed by
- `$2` the current user name
  and if you entered a command every time you get the prompt back it will play a sound file to get my attention that the command that i was running was finished.

And here is my ps1 for who loves it:

[image]

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[0;43m\]\[\033[1;34m\]██▓▒░\[\033[1;32m\]\u\[\033[1;30m\]⌘ \[\033[1;32m\]\h:\[\033[1;31m\]\w░▒▓█\[\033[0;31m\]█▓░\[\033[0;32m\]⇒᚜\!:\#᚛\[\033[00m\]\$ \[$(~/sound2.sh \# \u)'
```

And my terminal looks like:
[image]

Comment: You should use the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable for running commands before a prompt, not `PS1`.

Comment: But it works.
And how to make what you say (Is it using the `trap '' DEBUG` or what? give me an example please)? @muru

Comment: Just set `PROMPT_COMMAND='whatever command you want to run'`, for example, `PROMPT_COMMAND='spd-say welcome'`.

Comment: But using your method i can't know number of commands entered into this shell session as i did using `$#` in ps1 so i can't know if you just opened the terminal or you just entered a command before.

Comment: Maybe. I'm just saying that running commands is what `PROMPT_COMMAND` is for.

Comment: Thanks it really worked i tried it, but why didn't you answer from the beginning i was making a lot of search for something like this (+1).

Comment: I didn't see the question until you answered it yourself. :) (which reminds me: +1)

Answer (score 0):

Put any one of the below lines before the user input statement.

```
echo -en "\007"
```

or

```
echo -ne '\a' and printf '\a'
```

Comment: hay i said \a character is not working with me on my laptop so i need to do the mplayer command to play any sound.